# How can I select one section of a UITableView in UITests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing

I have a TableView that shows some sections. As the user taps on the sections the cells beneath each section appear.

I want to select a section to simulate a touch

Tried with the predicate

```
XCUIApplication* app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app launch];
XCUIElement* section = [app.tables elementMatchingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"description like MySection"]];
[section tap];
```

Tried to access the first cell on my TableView and didn`t worked.

```
XCUIElement* section = [app.tables elementBoundByIndex:0];
[section tap];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give your section headers an accessibility identifier. If your section headers are dynamic, you can give them all the same accessibility identifier and then choose one by index:

```
XCUIElement *table = [app.tables elementBoundByIndex: 0];
XCUIElementQuery *sections = [table.otherElements matchingIdentifier: "MySection"];
XCUIElement *section = [sections elementBoundByIndex: 0];
[section tap];
```

Otherwise, you can access by accessibility identifier directly:

```
XCUIElement *section = table.otherElements["MySection"];
```